# Automatically assigning p-value position in ggplot loop

Tags: ggplot2, compare, stat

I am running an mapply loop on a huge set of data to graph 13 parameters for 19 groups. This is working great except the p-value position. Due to the data varying for each plot I cannot assign position using label.y = 125 for example, in some plots it is in the middle of the bar/error bar. However, I can't assign it higher without having it way to high on other graphs. Is there a way to adjust to the data and error bars?

This is my graphing function and like I said the graph is great, except p-value position. Specifically, the stat compare means anova line.

```
ANOVA_plotter <- function(Variable, treatment, Grouping, df){
  Inputdf <- df %>%
  filter(Media == treatment, Group == Grouping) %>% 
  ggplot(aes_(x = ~ID, y = as.name(Variable))) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = ANOVA_Status), stat = "summary", fun = "mean", width = 0.9) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1), size = 1) +
  labs(title = paste(Variable, "in", treatment, "in Group", Grouping, sep = " ")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text = element_text(face="bold", size = 18 ), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,  hjust = 1)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1), width = 0.2) + 
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 125) +
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "t.test", paired = FALSE, ref.group = "Control")
}
```

I get graphs that look like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV9Ad.jpg)

But I can't assign it to label.y = 200 because of plots like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uStez.jpg)

Comment: You might be able to set `y = Inf` and adjusting the `vjust` parameter accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you. Would I have to do that for each graph or could I set it up in the loop somehow to automatically adjust? I know I may be asking something that is out of R's capability